# chrome/safari issue: <p> contains 2 hidden <span>, each containing a <div>, but the 1st is shown

Tags: google-chrome, safari, html

The following snippet runs fine in FF/IE (nothing is displayed) but in chrome/safari, the 1st span is displayed!

```
<p>
    <span style = "display:none"><div>inner</div></span>
    <span style = "display:none"><div>inner</div></span>
</p>
```

Anyone with an explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [content model of `span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) (what it can contain) is *phrasing content*. [The `div` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) isn't phrasing content, it's flow content. You can't validly have a `div` inside a `span`, and so what a browser does when it sees that is going to be implementation-specific.

For things like this, the W3C validator service is handy. For instance, [here's an example](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://jsbin.com/uwuwa3&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline) of asking the validator service to validate [this page](http://jsbin.com/uwuwa3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<p><span><div>foo</div></span></p>
</body>
```

...where the validator quite correctly complains about various things.

Comment: +1 using the validator is one of the best things I ever did as I was learning

Answer (score 2):

You should not place a block level element like `div` inside an inline element like `span`. If you look at the generated source of the page, you will see that the first `div` terminates the `span`, and is therefore not hidden. Why this does not happen with the second one is beyond me.

Just keep in mind that nesting a block element inside an inline element *will* lead to unexpected behavior.